# Как верстать подобный блок?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

Есть блок спидометра, но вообще нет идей как правильно сверстать обводку с заполнением скорости..
Единственное что приходит на ум - сделать круг и задать ему border, но нет идей как заполнять border фиолетовым цветом. Буду рад любым идеям и решениям.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а давай ка я сделаю

Comment: Думаю, что без SVG, весьма затруднительно будет. Так что советую добавить к вопросу соответствующую метку, чтобы знающие эту тему люди заглянули. Ну и здесь в поиске наберите "круговой прогресс" - может придёт идея.

Comment: пример - https://github.com/hongkiat/svg-meter-gauge

Comment: Спасибо большое, то что нужно!

Comment: @soledar10: зачем Вы уводите людей с ruSO и превращаете базу знаний в коллекцию ссылок?

Comment: @UModeL - по вашему, если пользователь пришел на этот сайт, ответ (примерное решение) должен содержать только ссылку с ruSO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Один из вариантов [highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-speedometer)

Пример

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
      type: 'gauge',
      plotBackgroundColor: null,
      plotBackgroundImage: null,
      plotBorderWidth: 0,
      plotShadow: false
    },

    title: {
      text: 'Speedometer'
    },

    pane: {
      startAngle: -150,
      endAngle: 150,
      background: [{
        backgroundColor: {
          linearGradient: {
            x1: 0,
            y1: 0,
            x2: 0,
            y2: 1
          },
          stops: [
            [0, '#FFF'],
            [1, '#333']
          ]
        },
        borderWidth: 0,
        outerRadius: '109%'
      }, {
        backgroundColor: {
          linearGradient: {
            x1: 0,
            y1: 0,
            x2: 0,
            y2: 1
          },
          stops: [
            [0, '#333'],
            [1, '#FFF']
          ]
        },
        borderWidth: 1,
        outerRadius: '107%'
      }, {
        // default background
      }, {
        backgroundColor: '#DDD',
        borderWidth: 0,
        outerRadius: '105%',
        innerRadius: '103%'
      }]
    },

    // the value axis
    yAxis: {
      min: 0,
      max: 200,

      minorTickInterval: 'auto',
      minorTickWidth: 1,
      minorTickLength: 10,
      minorTickPosition: 'inside',
      minorTickColor: '#666',

      tickPixelInterval: 30,
      tickWidth: 2,
      tickPosition: 'inside',
      tickLength: 10,
      tickColor: '#666',
      labels: {
        step: 2,
        rotation: 'auto'
      },
      title: {
        text: 'km/h'
      },
      plotBands: [{
        from: 0,
        to: 120,
        color: '#55BF3B' // green
      }, {
        from: 120,
        to: 160,
        color: '#DDDF0D' // yellow
      }, {
        from: 160,
        to: 200,
        color: '#DF5353' // red
      }]
    },

    series: [{
      name: 'Speed',
      data: [80],
      tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' km/h'
      }
    }]

  },
  // Add some life
  function(chart) {
    if (!chart.renderer.forExport) {
      setInterval(function() {
        var point = chart.series[0].points[0],
          newVal,
          inc = Math.round((Math.random() - 0.5) * 20);

        newVal = point.y + inc;
        if (newVal < 0 || newVal > 200) {
          newVal = point.y - inc;
        }

        point.update(newVal);

      }, 3000);
    }
  });
```

```css
#container {
  height: 400px;
}

.highcharts-figure,
.highcharts-data-table table {
  min-width: 310px;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

.highcharts-data-table table {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
  margin: 10px auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.highcharts-data-table caption {
  padding: 1em 0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #555;
}

.highcharts-data-table th {
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.highcharts-data-table td,
.highcharts-data-table th,
.highcharts-data-table caption {
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.highcharts-data-table thead tr,
.highcharts-data-table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #f8f8f8;
}

.highcharts-data-table tr:hover {
  background: #f1f7ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
  <div id="container"></div>
  <p class="highcharts-description">
    Chart showing use of multiple panes and axis plot bands with a gauge series. The chart is updated dynamically every few seconds.
  </p>
</figure>
```